# How to paint r x r field with n different color, without using same color at same line, with DP

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I want to ask how to solve this problem with DP.

The problem is: 'Make a program that calculates how many ways to paint r x r field with n different colors, without using the same color at same row and column.'

I tried to solve it with back-tracking, but it took so much time.
Also with BFS, it took a lot of memory. (And it was not so fast.)
And somebody told me to solve it with algorithm DLX, but I think there will be an easier solution.

Will can it be solved with DP? 10 x 10 field with 10 colors should be filled in 1~2 seconds. Please help!

Comment: Can you post some complete code about the ways you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a solution with DP but their is another method which will need to traverse the matrix once without any extra space and with O(n^2) complexity(which I think will also be the case while using DP).

Starting from cell(0,0) paint it with color paint_no and then increment row and column by 1, but remember to take row%n and col%n because at some point row or column might be greater than 'n'.

The solution works because when ever you are painting a box with a color the next box will be painted in next row and next column and so on for other boxes.

```
starting_cell_row=0;
starting_cell_col=0;
count=0;
for(paint_no, 1, n)
{
    count=0;
    row=starting_cell_row;
    col=starting_cell_col;
    while(count<n)
    {
        matrix[row][col]=paint_no;
        row=(row+1)%n;
        col=(col+1)%n;
        count++;
    }
    starting_cell_col++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a well-known task of finding the number of Latin Squares
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square

The task has NOT a common solution.

But for computational finding all permutations there exist a [Jacobson and Matthews' algorithm](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/(SICI)1520-6610(1996)4:6%3C405::AID-JCD3%3E3.0.CO;2-J/abstract;jsessionid=E51CB3CB3FA21154644293BD62C52ADC.f04t03).